# Send Email to Edit MediaWiki

Tags: mysql, database, email, mediawiki

How can I enable this workflow:

1. Send an email to me@mywikiserver.com with the subject **MyWikiPage**
2. mywikiserver.com edits **MyWikiPage** and appends the email contents to the page

I'd like to avoid manually writing SQL statements to update the database.  For example, is there a Python library that can edit the MediaWiki on the server?

Comment: Found http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailToWiki and http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit ... any possibility someone has a python library to hook into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three python mediawiki api accessing tools: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Python

Answer (score 1):

The maintenance script edit.php in the maintenance directory allows page editing and also allows you to assign the user who made the edit.